# colClasses date and time read.csv

Tags: r, read.csv

I have some data of the form:

```
date,time,val1,val2
20090503,0:05:12,107.25,1
20090503,0:05:17,108.25,20
20090503,0:07:45,110.25,5
20090503,0:07:56,106.25,5
```

that comes from a csv file.  I am relatively new to R, so I tried

```
data <-read.csv("sample.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

and using `POSIXlt`, as well as `POSIXct` in the `colClasses` argument, but I cant seem to be able to create one column or 'variable' out of my date and time data.  I want to do so, so I can then choose arbitrary timeframes over which to calculate running statistics such as max, min, mean (and then boxplots, etc.).

I also thought that I might convert it to a time series and get around it that way,

```
dataTS <-ts(data)
```

but have yet been able to use the start, end, and frequency to my advantage.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this upon reading the data in to R using the `colClasses` argument because the data span two "columns" in the CSV file. Instead, load the data and process the `date` and `time` columns into a single `POSIXlt` variable:

```
dat <- read.csv(textConnection("date,time,val1,val2
                               20090503,0:05:12,107.25,1
                               20090503,0:05:17,108.25,20
                               20090503,0:07:45,110.25,5
                               20090503,0:07:56,106.25,5"))
dat <- within(dat, Datetime <- as.POSIXlt(paste(date, time),
                                          format = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

[I presume it is year month day??, If not use `"%Y%d%m %H:%M:%S"`]

Which gives:

```
> head(dat)
      date    time   val1 val2            Datetime
1 20090503 0:05:12 107.25    1 2009-05-03 00:05:12
2 20090503 0:05:17 108.25   20 2009-05-03 00:05:17
3 20090503 0:07:45 110.25    5 2009-05-03 00:07:45
4 20090503 0:07:56 106.25    5 2009-05-03 00:07:56
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date    : int  20090503 20090503 20090503 20090503
 $ time    : Factor w/ 4 levels "0:05:12","0:05:17",..: 1 2 3 4
 $ val1    : num  107 108 110 106
 $ val2    : int  1 20 5 5
 $ Datetime: POSIXlt, format: "2009-05-03 00:05:12" "2009-05-03 00:05:17" ...
```

You can now delete `date` and `time if you wish:

```
> dat <- dat[, -(1:2)]
> head(dat)
    val1 val2            Datetime
1 107.25    1 2009-05-03 00:05:12
2 108.25   20 2009-05-03 00:05:17
3 110.25    5 2009-05-03 00:07:45
4 106.25    5 2009-05-03 00:07:56
```